# File permissions in filezilla not working (707)

Tags: permissions, ftp, filezilla

Status: Set permissions of '/images' to '707'
Command:    SITE CHMOD 707 images
Response:   500 'SITE CHMOD 707 images': command not understood

I do not fully understand why this is not working. I am trying to set a folder to accept user submitted images, but it keep getting this response when I set the file permission to 707. Why is it doing this?

Answer (score 0):

This is most likely your FTP server disallowing file permission changes. Try updating them from your servers web panel instead.